# How to update content via Google Sites API?

Tags: c#, google-sites, google-data-api

My apologies if this has already been requested/answered before, but I'm having a hard time trying to find information on the web about this.  I've been tasked to find a way to directly update the content of a Google Sites page (Such as a text box or image) using the API.

I've been looking about the web for examples of doing this using C#, and have not found much to go by.  I have some experience with writing/calling REST and SOAP APIs, but I can't seem to work out what Google uses for its API.

I'm struggling as to how I approach this, as the few examples I have found don't really walk through the code, so they leave me little to understand in order to manipulate it to what I want to achieve.  One site I did find was [Sites API Demo](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/sites/dotnet/SitesAPIDemo.cs)

Does anybody have any examples, or able to provide a simple example of updating content on a Google Site?

I appreciate any help you can give.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I have successfully updated the content of a google sites page using [the library provided here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-sites/), and following [the example in the wiki](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-sites/wiki/Home).

I compiled the source as a .dll and added it as a reference to my project.